# Calculate a sum of fraction of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am trying to calculate this fraction:

$\sum_{n=1}^{101} \frac{100 \choose n-1}{103 \choose n}$. I wonder if there is some identity about binomial coefficient that would be helpful here.

Comment: $$ \binom {a} {b}=\dfrac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

Comment: I am not sure it helps but $\dfrac{100 \choose n-1}{103 \choose n} = \dfrac{100!\,n!\,(103-n)!}{(n-1)!\,(101-n)!\,103!} = \dfrac{n \, (103-n)\,(102-n)}{101\times102\times 103}$

Comment: Once simplified, this is just a sum over the values of some cubic polynomial in $n$.  There are closed formulas for such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in an earlier comment we can simplify:

$$
\dfrac{\binom{100}{n-1}}{\binom{103}{n}} = \dfrac{n \, (103-n)\,(102-n)}{101\times102\times 103}
$$

so our sum is:

$$
\dfrac{1}{{101\times102\times 103}}\sum_{n=1}^{101}(n^3-205n^2+10506n)
$$

Next, we can utilize [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to simplify to:

$$
\dfrac{1}{{101\times102\times 103}} \left( \left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 - 205 \dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6} + 10506\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)
$$

Finally, substituting n = 101 gives us:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{101} \frac{100 \choose n-1}{103 \choose n} = \dfrac{26}{3}
$$